# Adding CommonCrypto to custom Swift framework

Tags: xcode, frameworks

I’m building a Swift framework which seems relatively simple. Then I needed to import CommonCrypto.

In the framework’s .h file I added the line

```
#import <CommonCrypto/CommonCrypto.h>
```

and included `Security.framework` in `Link Binary with Libraries` for the framework’s target.

When I build I get the following build error:

```
Include of non-modular header inside framework module ‘MyKit'
```

I’ve tried changing the `Allow Non-modular Includes In Framework Modules` to `YES` and `NO` and tried every combination for both the framework target and the project with no luck.

The `MyKit.h`’s Target Membership is set to `Public` and is ticked for MyKit too.

Comment: Any fix with that? @AdamCarter

Comment: I think I ended up finding a 3rd party Swift framework for CommonCrypto. Not sure if this has been "fixed" since though...

Answer (score 0):

In Xcode 10.0 you'll be able to import CommonCrypto. As a work around I suggest inverting that dependency with a protocol and importing CommonCrypto in your framework client.